# RequestContext Via Property has Machine Name instead of URL in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, url, httprequest

I am doing some work with OAuth and need to get the URL of the request. To do this I am doing the following:

```
operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties.Via
```

This was working great in Visual Studio Development Server because it would return

```
http://localhost:12345/{myrequest}
```

However, when pushed to IIS, and setting my project properties to use Custom Web Server with a value of this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/
```

This is now showing a URL like the following in my RequestContext:

```
http://{machinename}/{myrequest}
```

Instead of:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/{myrequest}
```

Is this an IIS setting? To get around this, I am forced to modify the URI instance to swap out the machine name with the domain name. This is non-ideal.

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: This is a serious problem, as you should not be tightly coupling your application to your domain name. The machine name is returned because that *is* the server name. Can you provide an explanation as to why this is creating a problem, and then maybe we can better provide an answer.